# Getting pid of the program just started in Python

Tags: python, scripting

I need to create startup and stop scripts for a python program. My temporary solution was to have the startup.sh:

```
python -m root.scripts.run 
python server.py 'localhost' 42345
```

This starts my program and a server that is needed to do some computations. Now for stop.sh I just do:

```
killall -m Python
killall python
killall Python
```

This works and stops my program. However I need to find a less "brutal" solution, since this obviously kills all python related processes. A solution I'm thinking of (not sure if it is possible) is in the startup.sh to get the PID of the two started processes and store them in a file somewhere. Then for the stop.sh I would just get those pids and kill those processes. Now I have a few questions:

1. Is my proposed solution viable? If so how can I get the pid of the recently started processes ? In terms of storing them and then getting them from a file, is this doable and if so how?
2. Do you have any other proposed solutions for my problem?
3. In terms of cross-platform, how hard would it be to mimic something like this on windows?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the [`subprocess`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html) module to start the program from Python (this is the recommended way anyway).  The object returned from `subprocess.Popen` has `terminate()` and `kill()` methods as well as a `pid` attribute that you can save and use for stopping the process again.

On Unix systems, you might consider saving the PID in a file in `/var/run/<yourscript>.pid` (see the [Filesystem Hierarchy Standard](http://www.pathname.com/fhs/2.2/fhs-5.13.html)), then read this file to retrieve the PID when requested to stop.

Comment: Thanks for the input. But I'm not sure if I understand your suggestion. So you are saying I should replace my startup.sh shell script with a python script. Then in this python script use subprocess.Popen(root.scripts.run) subprocess.Popen(server.py). From this i get my PID's and store them somewhere. Then replace the stop.sh shell with a python script also and get those pids and kill the processes. Is this correct ?

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your question.  Why don't you just write an init shell script based on some existing one?  For example, Debian systems come with a skeleton file `/etc/init.d/skeleton` that you can easily adapt to start your Python program.

Answer (score 1):

I would replace your startup.sh for a Python script which runs both scripts. Use subprocess.Popen() for running new processes and terminate() for killing them.

Python solves your third question. Otherwise you have to use cygwin/mingw under Windows.

Comment: But I need to be able to call start and stop separately. I mean the user should be able to call let's say python start_program.py to start the application. Then if something goes wrong or he just wants to stop he would python stop_program.py. Your suggestion would be to create only one Python script which would be started like python app.py "start" respectively python app.py "stop" ?

Comment: Exactly. That's the idea: Use app.py [start|stop] and parse the argument from the command line. You could even add more flags or arguments by using [argparse](http://docs.python.org/library/argparse.html#module-argparse) module. This approach works both Linux and Windows.